# How can you center text (vertically and horizontally) in a table, and prevent cell resizing?

Tags: css, html

Overall what I'm aiming for is a table where all the text is centred, and when text is entered, the cells won't resize.

Originally my code was like this:

**HTML**

```
<table id="main_table">
    <tr>
        <td><div/></td>
        <td><div/></td>
        <td><div/></td>
        <td><div/></td>
        <td><div/></td>
   </tr>
   <!--several more rows here-->
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#table-main
{
    height:1000px;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

#table-main td
{
    background-color: #F3F5EF;
    border: 1px #bbb solid;
    color: #333;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    cursor: default;
}

#table-main td > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Which appears like this. Not that the rows with text in them are higher than rows without text.
[image]

I read that you can stop this resizing by adding:

```
 display: inline-block;
```

This does stop the resizing, but it then prevents the text from being centered:
[image]

Is there any way to have the best of both worlds? And in addition, is there any way to centre the text vertically as well?

Comment: I don't get it but you are trying to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/jAG3j/ ?

Comment: @Miguel What he has done is place the `vertical-align: middle;` property on the `td` instead of on the `div`. He has also specifically set the height of the `td`, so it doesn't resize.

Comment: It's by default centered vertically and horizontally, my question is, do you want that happen without fixed width and height for table TDs? or equal columns? if you can post your table styles please do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay while hsobhy posted some working code, I think a better solution is to explain how to fix the original code. Adding `display: inline-block;` to the div worked fine to get rid of the cell resizing, but then:

1. The table cells (*not the div*) needed to be specified as centered in order to get the horizontal centering:

   ```
   #main_table td, #main_table th{
       /*All the other properties*/
       text-align: center;
   }
   ```
2. I was setting the height of the div, which I shouldn't have. Removing it gave me vertical centering as well:

   ```
   #table-main td > div {
      /*Other stuff/* 
      height: 100%; /*This needed to go/*
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Posted an example on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LN4p/3/)

## CSS

```
table {width:100%;;} 
table, th, td
{
border: 1px solid #eee; 
}
table td{ padding:10px; 
    width:19% !important; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height: 80px !important; 
    overflow:visible;
    line-height: 40px;
}


td > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 14px;
    display:inline-block
}
```

## HTML

```
<table id="main_table">
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div>1</div></td>
         <td align="center"><div>Please note, the easing function names changed in version  1.2.Please note, the easing function names changed in version  1.2. </div></td>
         <td align="center"><div>3</div></td>
         <td align="center"><div>4</div></td>
         <td align="center"><div>5</div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

## EDIT

CSS update for better vertical align (please note rest of text is hidden ... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LN4p/3/) and [old one](http://jsfiddle.net/7LN4p/2/)